# String.format prints 'question mark' as output

Tags: java, string

I am fairly new to programming and was following a tutorial on youtube and I got stuck at this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(String.format("%02d", 1));
}
```

The code is supposed to print `01` as output but instead I get `??`, just 2 question marks. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Your code prints  `01` [check](http://ideone.com/hPuQDx)

Comment: It doesn't. I've tried both in eclipse and cmd. 
Plus I've tried another things as well, it always prints just "????"

Comment: try `System.out.format(Locale.US, "%02d", 1);`. Also set your project encoding as UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, I found the mistake

Comment: What was the issue ?

Comment: The numbers were being displayed in hindi format. And the output just displayed them as question marks. Don't even know why eclipse is changing these numbers to hindi numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. Eclipse was using hindi format numbers to display output (don't know why ?). Setting project encoding to UTF-8 allowed me to see them instead of 'question marks'.