# System.out.printf does not print formats in netbeans 11.2(java)

Tags: java

I tried to print integers by using this format:
int x=7 --> output = 07
so I have write this code:

```
public class test{
public static void main(String[] args){
int x=7;
System.out.printf("your converted number = %02d",x);
}
}
```

but the OUTPUT in Netbeans 11.2 IDE is :

```
your converted number = ??
```

how can I fix this error in my own Netbeans version?

Comment: That's very unexpected. Is that copy-and-pasted code, or did you re-type it?

Comment: Im new to stackoverflow so thats why  I was not write my problem in correctly way...sorry

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No worries. I'm asking because I want to make sure we're looking at the *exact* code that is causing the problem.  Please use copy and paste, both for the code and for the output.  For the record, when I run the code in your quest, I get the output `your converted number = 07`.

Comment: Yes...If you copy this code in your Netbeans 11.2 IDE you will see the same output

Comment: I don't use Netbeans, sorry. I use IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String.format prints 'question mark' as output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049590/string-format-prints-question-mark-as-output)

Comment: Unfortunately no...because thats for Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 1):

I think it may have to do with internationalization setting for your locale. See: [String.format prints 'question mark' as output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049590/string-format-prints-question-mark-as-output)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that link''s answer  was for Eclipse IDE and my IDE is Netbeans

Comment: See this answer for Netbeans console encoding configuration https://stackoverflow.com/a/27848261/6250649

Comment: Still not worked in my IDE ...can you please download netbeans 11.2 and test my code  ?Maybe after that you can give me more clear answere

Comment: I am not even going to try because I know the results depend on your/my computer's operating system country and language (locale) settings that conflict on your setup but will work fine for countries using Latin alphabet and English codepage settings, see: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk8-jre8-suported-locales.html